# Prevent vector image deformation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector image as the background of an action bar, my problem is that when the bar changes sizes the vector gets deformed and the animation doesn't look natural. Is there a way to prevent this?

[image]

Here is the vector "bar_left_angle":

```
  <vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="51"
        android:viewportWidth="173" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <path android:fillColor="#1B5E20" android:pathData="M173.859,0l0,27.274l-147.496,24.278l-26.363,-29.307l0,-22.245"/>
    </vector>
```

And here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/productsBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/bar_left_angle"
        app:elevation="0dp" >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" >
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_left_angle"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```